# Excel Formula - Reference Sheet based on key word instead of the full name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a few excel files that have different fruit information written on different sheets.

Example:

1. Apples
2. Carrots
3. Bananas
4. Orange
5. Kiwi

The problem is that the "x)" changes based on the number of fruits there are in the excel file. Therefore, in one file the oranges can be "4)" but in another "3)" or "5)".

I am wondering if there is a way to create a formula where I can reference the sheet for Oranges and somehow ignore the "x)" at the beginning.

So far, I managed to do it by using VBA to loop through every sheet and remove the first 3 characters. However, I am curious if there is just some sort of a function that can do that and not use VBA. Something similar to the VLOOK logic where if it is TRUE it will take the approximate match instead of having FALSE for an exact match.

Thanks!

Comment: `=MATCH("*"&"Orange",A1:A5,0)`?

Comment: Kind of, but I need to match a sheet name not a cell. For example: `='3) Orange'!B36` where it can also be `='2) Orange'!B36` or `='5) Orange'!B36` or any other number.

Comment: Can you use `INDIRECT` here to construct the sheet name? If there is some logic to determine what the number corresponding to each fruit is for a given file, then you could take this approach.